# What function should I use to return a value after comparing values in 2 columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have "Customer number" values in column A and "Part number" values in column B from my worksheet #1. Column C is where I'm trying to return a value using the correct function in C2 and beyond. In my worksheet #2, I have the same A & B columns as well as "Quantities shipped" in column C. This is the information I'm trying to bring in worksheet #1. Basically, the function needs to look at customer number in A2 and part number in B2 from worksheet #1, then look at where those 2 match in the same row from worksheet #2...to return the worksheet #2 column C information from that row in to my worksheet #1 C2 cell.

Added note: there's no repetitiveness meaning the combination of customer number with part number is only there once.

Help!

Thanks,
Pat

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2)
```

Or if you have FILTER():

```
=@FILTER(Sheet2!C:C,(Sheet2!A:A=A2)*(Sheet2!B:B=B2),0)
```

See similar question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: Thank you! The SUMIFS function works on those "part number" cells that are numeric but not those that are alpha-numeric, any idea how I can make them work?

Comment: According to your description C is `"Quantities shipped"` which I assume is a number.  Column A and B should not matter if they are numeric or text as long as the base values(not the formatted) are the same.

Comment: Check your data to see if any of the text have spaces that the other does not.

Comment: Thank you...it worked!!

Comment: Also, you need to add the $ before using the dropdown ;)

Comment: @Pat not needed unless you are dragging it across columns.  You want the A2 and B2 to change and the full columns will not.  Unless you changed the full columns to just the dataset....